# How I can retrieve all records with 1-2 queries using regular SQL and Linq-To-Entities?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I uploaded simplified [SQL ERD](https://picasaweb.google.com/TheAteist/Forums#5603997855998903538) on Picasa.
I tried to do it but I manage to it with more than 2 queries.

I need to retrieve all records from table **D** with specific **E_Id** of table **E** and specific **TypeId** of table **A**

**UPDATED**: I need also that all records from **B** that mapped to **TypeId**  will be alse retrieved even if not all of them are mapped in table **C** (some kind of LEFT-RIGHT JOIN)

I need to do it at most 2 queries and then convert it to Linq-To-Entites statement
If it can be done with 1 query I prefer with 1 query

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you just want a bunch of inner joins bringing all of the tables together and then filtering on Typeid and E_id - is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL query:

```
SELECT D.*
FROM D 
INNER JOIN C ON C.Id = D.C_Id
INNER JOIN B ON B.Id = C.B_Id
INNER JOIN A ON A.Id = B.A_Id
WHERE D.E_Id = @eId AND A.TypeId = @typeId

SELECT B.*
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON A.Id = B.A_Id
WHERE A.TypeId = @typeId
```

Linq directly (if navigation properties don't exists):

```
var query = from d in context.D
            join c in context.C on c.Id equals d.cId
            join b in context.B on b.Id equals c.bId
            join a in context.A on a.Id equals b.aId
            where d.eId == eId && a.TypeId == typeId
            select d;

var query2 = from b in context.B
             join a in context.A on a.Id equals b.aId
             where a.TypeId == typeId
             select b;
```

Linq if navigation properties are correctly set up:

```
var query = from d in context.D
            where d.E.Id == eId &&
                  d.C.B.A.TypeId == typeId
            select d;  

var query2 = from b in context.B
             where b.A.TypeId == typeId
             select b;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the condition. I updated my post. If you can please update your answer. Thank you

Comment: @theateist: I edited my answer. You must use two queries because you want two different result sets.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why the below won't work for you?

```
SELECT D.*
FROM D
INNER JOIN C
ON C.Id = D.C_Id
INNER JOIN B
ON B.Id = C.B_Id
INNER JOIN A
ON A.Id = B.A_Id
WHERE D.E_id = <The E_Id> AND A.Typeid = <The Typeid>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the condition. I updated my post. If you can please update your answer. Thank you

Comment: @theateist - do you require fields from more tables than just D in your results then?

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry if I didn't wrote the question correctly. I was in hurry.